# Latex: usepackage on part of the document

Tags: latex, document, tex

I would like to use `\usepackage{}` only on part of my document. The other part of the document is completely made up and now it would be out of order by entering this package in that part as well. But I don't know how to use `usepackage` only on part of the document?

Answer (score -1):

You must put the `\usepackage`  before the beginning of the document.

Your .tex must look like this :

```latex
\documentclass{<the class you want>}

%All the packages
\usepackage{<package>}

\begin{document}
Your text
\end{document}
```

The package will apply to all your document, but there is no problem if you include several packages at the beginning.

If you have a specific problem, please post a minimal example of what went wrong.